# Optimal placement of 4 reaction wheels?

Tags: reaction-wheel, attitude

What is the optimal orientation to place 4 reaction wheels, such that complete 3 axis control can be maintained at all times?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most often they're configured in a "pyramid", which is done for both controllability and redundancy reasons (it's tolerant to one wheel failure).

That said, there are many subtleties to this problem, and all spacecraft with reaction wheels do not necessarily follow the same design. The paper "Sun-Tracking Commands and Reaction Wheel Sizing with Configuration Optimization" by Hari Hablani is available [here](http://www.aero.iitb.ac.in/~hbhablani/Papers_for_Homepage/JGCD_1994_Sun_Tracking_Wheel_Configuration.pdf) [PDF], and discusses reaction wheel sizing and configuration considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Illustration of tetrahedral arrangement of reaction wheels. This provides one redundant wheel.

[image]

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Tetraederanordnung_Reaktionsraeder.jpg/791px-Tetraederanordnung_Reaktionsraeder.jpg?20090708130911